# Printing each number in the range specified by two random integers

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << " Enter the small number " << std::endl;
  int v1 = 0;
  std::cin >> v1;

  std::cout << " Enter the large number " << std::endl;
  int v2 = 0;
  std::cin >> v2;

  int x = 0;
  while (x <= v2-1) {
    x = v1+1;
    ++x;
  }

  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This code gives no error but i couldn't get any output after input of two numbers. But, it works with a for loop like this;

```
{
  for (int x = v1+1; x <= v2-1; ++x)
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

what is the mistake i should avoid using while loop ?

Comment: You are initializing `x` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = 0;
while (x <= v2-1) {
   x = v1+1;
   ++x;}
```

You get an infinite loop here, the value of x is always either v1+1, or v1+2.

use this:

```
int x = v1+1;
while (x++ <= v2-1) {
cout<<x;
}
```